# Can I run Apache Ignite Transaction with Thin Client for .Net?

Tags: ignite

Is it possible to initiate and commit/rollback an Ignite transaction when using the Thin Client for .Net? I didn't find the method to begin a transaction.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transactional API is about to be added to the .NET thin client. Watch [this Ignite JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-7369).